# How to declare variables to be used in multiple modules in python

Tags: python, class, import, global-variables, constants

This question has probably been asked before, but the other posts I found on Stack Overflow mainly dealt with changing global variables and importing functions etc. Perhaps my wording wasn't right when I did a quick search.

I am starting to code in Python, and I was wondering what the most efficient and proper way to do the following is.

I have a parent module that I am importing to other modules. It has the structure:

```
# some import statements go here

# Constants that need to be the same for all objects
a = 1
b = 2
...

# A class with some useful functions
class Def():
    def __init__(self):
    ...
```

I am importing this module in some others, to use the functions in the Def class. But I also want all the modules importing it to have access to the constants that I declared outside the class.

I declared them outside, as I want those values to be used wherever I called them in that module. I did not want to attach them to objects (and have to refer to them as self.a, self.b etc.) and they will be constants throughout every module I am using.

Some of the options I am considering are:

1. Declare these as global variables in a separate class, and import
   that class in every module
2. Use `from parentmodule import *`

I am not sure if either of these will work, and if there is a standard way of doing this. Conflicts in names of variables while doing the latter will not be a problem, because of the nature of the constants. In the context of my program, they are physical constants with unique names that will not be used to represent other variables.

Apologies if the question is too basic/previously asked, and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing the whole module will act as a sort of namespace, and it seems to me to be the simplest way to do it.  So you have "mystuff.py":

```
a = 1
b = 2

def MyFunc():
    ....
```

Then in your other modules:

```
import mystuff

print mystuff.a
print mystuff.b

mystuff.MyFunc()
```

Your solution to:

```
from mystuff import *
```

Works, but possibly conflicts and I'm thinking isn't what people consider "pythonic."

Comment: Is there a way to say that the variables are to be common in all modules, so that I don't have to keep typing mystuff.a, mystuff.b, etc.?

Comment: you could import mystuff.a as a, then you can just call the variable as a, this will work as long as you don't have too many variables since you need one line of code for each variable.

Comment: Or just `from mystuff import a`.

Comment: @GoK, honestly, if you want clarity in your code, it's better to use the import as a namespace.  If you don't want to do that, then yes, use the "from mystuff import *" construct.  It works; it's not wrong to do it, it's just my experience that it leads to name conflicts in other modules down the road, making it very difficult to debug and maintain - but it's not "wrong."  But yes, every module would need that line.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! I'll import each variable, there aren't too many that I need.